# App Requirements

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-10-universal

We've recently published an app to the windows store and found that there are some requirements (listed in the bottom of app's store page) that are in our case the following:
    Mouse
    Keyboard
    Touch
    Camera

It says that Keyboard and touch are required at the same time, but app works fine with touch only or keyboard and mouse only. The main problem is that store does not allow user to review the app on device that does not fit all requirements. As a result, user cannot review the app on mobile phone (it doesn't have keyboard and mouse) and on the desktop pc (it doesn't have touch support and camera sometimes)

Does anybody know where do these requirements come from and how can we change or completely remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set this in the dashboard when you submit your app. There are checkboxes for [Hardware preferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/enter-app-properties#hardware-preferences) in the submission's app properties page.

[image: app properties page]

Comment: That's it! Thanks.